Controller neither will be rendered nor routed in Shopware6
I'm coding a plugin for Shopware 6.2.3.1 using php 7.2.
Following code will return 404 Error. I did following:
(1) installing plugin and activating it using console
(2)cleaning cache
Nothing fixes this issue. Under localhost, everything works quite fine, but plugin has been developed with PHP 8.1 and Shopware 6.5. Differences are commentated in code. Thx a lot in advanced. Here is Controller code


?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace WtUpdateProducts\Storefront\Controller;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService;
use Shopware\Storefront\Controller\StorefrontController;
//following classes have been depreceated and should only be used prior to Shopware 6.4.11.0
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\RouteScope;
/*use following class up to 6.5 major version
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Attribute\Route;
*/
use Shopware\Storefront\Page\GenericPageLoaderInterface;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use WtUpdateProducts\classes\Paths;
use WtUpdateProducts\classes\ReadOutXML;
use WtUpdateProducts\classes\Database;
use DateTime;
use Exception;

/*  Use following Routing up to Shopware 6.5 major version
#[Route(defaults: ['_routeScope' => ['storefront']])]
*/

/**
 * @RouteScope(scopes={"storefront"})
 */
class UpdateController extends StorefrontController
{
    /*  usde following code up to php 7.4
    private GenericPageLoaderInterface $genericPageLoader;
    private SystemConfigService $systemConfigService;
    private EntityRepository $mediaRepository;
    private Database $db;
    */
    private $genericPageLoader;
    private $systemConfigService;
    private $mediaRepository;
    private $db;
    private const ROOTFILE1 = 'Artikel.xml';
    private const ROOTFILE2 = 'SalesPrice.xml';


    public function __construct(GenericPageLoaderInterface $genericPageLoader, SystemConfigService $systemConfigService, EntityRepository $mediaRepository, Database $db)
    {
        //create Dependency Injections,which are based on services.xml
        $this->genericPageLoader = $genericPageLoader;
        $this->systemConfigService = $systemConfigService;
        $this->mediaRepository = $mediaRepository;
        $this->db = $db;
    }


    /*  Use following Routing up to Shopware 6.5 major version
    #[Route(path: 'wt/update', name: 'frontend.update', methods: ['POST', 'GET'])]
    */

    /**
     * @Route("/wt/update", name="frontend.download", methods={"GET","POST"}, defaults={"XmlHttpRequest"=true, "csrf_protected"=false})
     */
    public function showUpdateFormular(Request $request, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext, Context $context): Response
    {}



Here is routes.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing
        https://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <!--<import resource="../../Storefront/Controller/**/*Controller.php" type="annotation" />-->
    <import resource="../../Storefront/Controller/UpdateController.php" type="annotation" />
</routes>



and here is services.xml


<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="WtUpdateProducts\Storefront\Controller\UpdateController" public="true">
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Storefront\Page\GenericPageLoader"/>
            <argument type="service" id="Shopware\Core\System\SystemConfig\SystemConfigService"/>
            <argument type="service" id="media.repository"/>
            <argument type="service" id="WtUpdateProducts\classes\Database"/>
            <call method="setContainer">
                <argument type="service" id="service_container"/>
            </call>
            <call method="setTwig">
                <argument type="service" id="twig"/>
            </call>
        </service>
        <service id="WtUpdateProducts\classes\Database">
            <argument type="service" id="product.repository"/>
            <argument type="service" id="product_price.repository"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>



I'm totally confused,'cause using die() in constructor has no effects! As it seems, controller won't be rendered, at all, although I am able configuring it in backend. Calling {domain_url}/wt/update in frontend will call 404 error site without any entry in log. Any ideas, how to fix this?
If I try
php bin/console debug:router

route will shown!
